# Does $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$?

I was trying to compute the Galois group of $x^4-4*x^2+2=0$ and faced this problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Setting $\alpha := \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, we get:
$$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} \cdot \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2^2 - 2} = \sqrt{2},$$ so
$$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} = \frac{\alpha^2-2}{\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ then 
$$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a^2-2}{a} $$